# How to provide the correct key for Camellia cipher and encrypt in Java

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, camellia

I want build program with plain `text ="hello i'm jhon"` then encrypt to cipher text and then decrypt to plain text again. So first I search and get code from internet with format data integer. I found [camellia-java-BSD-1.0.1.tar.gz](https://info.isl.ntt.co.jp/crypt/eng/camellia/dl/camellia-java-BSD-1.0.1.tar.gz) from [here](https://info.isl.ntt.co.jp/crypt/eng/camellia/source_past.html).

So write this code but I get error

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at javaapplication1.Newclass.Camellia_EncryptBlock(Newclass.java:487)
    at javaapplication1.Newclass.main(Newclass.java:569)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

this is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

 int[] a={0,2};
 int[] b={0,3};
 int[]c={0,4};
 Newclass n=new Newclass();

  n.Camellia_EncryptBlock(a, b, c);}
```

and this is full code.
So I want to build with String not integer but with integer I get error so I don't get idea how I build with String

```
public class Newclass{


private final int SBOX1_1110[] = 
{
        0x70707000, 0x82828200, 0x2c2c2c00, 0xececec00, 0xb3b3b300, 0x27272700, 
        0xc0c0c000, 0xe5e5e500, 0xe4e4e400, 0x85858500, 0x57575700, 0x35353500, 
        0xeaeaea00, 0x0c0c0c00, 0xaeaeae00, 0x41414100, 0x23232300, 0xefefef00, 
        0x6b6b6b00, 0x93939300, 0x45454500, 0x19191900, 0xa5a5a500, 0x21212100, 
        0xededed00, 0x0e0e0e00, 0x4f4f4f00, 0x4e4e4e00, 0x1d1d1d00, 0x65656500, 
        0x92929200, 0xbdbdbd00, 0x86868600, 0xb8b8b800, 0xafafaf00, 0x8f8f8f00, 
        0x7c7c7c00, 0xebebeb00, 0x1f1f1f00, 0xcecece00, 0x3e3e3e00, 0x30303000, 
        0xdcdcdc00, 0x5f5f5f00, 0x5e5e5e00, 0xc5c5c500, 0x0b0b0b00, 0x1a1a1a00, 
        0xa6a6a600, 0xe1e1e100, 0x39393900, 0xcacaca00, 0xd5d5d500, 0x47474700, 
        0x5d5d5d00, 0x3d3d3d00, 0xd9d9d900, 0x01010100, 0x5a5a5a00, 0xd6d6d600, 
        0x51515100, 0x56565600, 0x6c6c6c00, 0x4d4d4d00, 0x8b8b8b00, 0x0d0d0d00, 
        0x9a9a9a00, 0x66666600, 0xfbfbfb00, 0xcccccc00, 0xb0b0b000, 0x2d2d2d00, 
        0x74747400, 0x12121200, 0x2b2b2b00, 0x20202000, 0xf0f0f000, 0xb1b1b100, 
        0x84848400, 0x99999900, 0xdfdfdf00, 0x4c4c4c00, 0xcbcbcb00, 0xc2c2c200, 
        0x34343400, 0x7e7e7e00, 0x76767600, 0x05050500, 0x6d6d6d00, 0xb7b7b700, 
        0xa9a9a900, 0x31313100, 0xd1d1d100, 0x17171700, 0x04040400, 0xd7d7d700, 
        0x14141400, 0x58585800, 0x3a3a3a00, 0x61616100, 0xdedede00, 0x1b1b1b00, 
        0x11111100, 0x1c1c1c00, 0x32323200, 0x0f0f0f00, 0x9c9c9c00, 0x16161600, 
        0x53535300, 0x18181800, 0xf2f2f200, 0x22222200, 0xfefefe00, 0x44444400, 
        0xcfcfcf00, 0xb2b2b200, 0xc3c3c300, 0xb5b5b500, 0x7a7a7a00, 0x91919100, 
        0x24242400, 0x08080800, 0xe8e8e800, 0xa8a8a800, 0x60606000, 0xfcfcfc00, 
        0x69696900, 0x50505000, 0xaaaaaa00, 0xd0d0d000, 0xa0a0a000, 0x7d7d7d00, 
        0xa1a1a100, 0x89898900, 0x62626200, 0x97979700, 0x54545400, 0x5b5b5b00, 
        0x1e1e1e00, 0x95959500, 0xe0e0e000, 0xffffff00, 0x64646400, 0xd2d2d200, 
        0x10101000, 0xc4c4c400, 0x00000000, 0x48484800, 0xa3a3a300, 0xf7f7f700, 
        0x75757500, 0xdbdbdb00, 0x8a8a8a00, 0x03030300, 0xe6e6e600, 0xdadada00, 
        0x09090900, 0x3f3f3f00, 0xdddddd00, 0x94949400, 0x87878700, 0x5c5c5c00, 
        0x83838300, 0x02020200, 0xcdcdcd00, 0x4a4a4a00, 0x90909000, 0x33333300, 
        0x73737300, 0x67676700, 0xf6f6f600, 0xf3f3f300, 0x9d9d9d00, 0x7f7f7f00, 
        0xbfbfbf00, 0xe2e2e200, 0x52525200, 0x9b9b9b00, 0xd8d8d800, 0x26262600, 
        0xc8c8c800, 0x37373700, 0xc6c6c600, 0x3b3b3b00, 0x81818100, 0x96969600, 
        0x6f6f6f00, 0x4b4b4b00, 0x13131300, 0xbebebe00, 0x63636300, 0x2e2e2e00, 
        0xe9e9e900, 0x79797900, 0xa7a7a700, 0x8c8c8c00, 0x9f9f9f00, 0x6e6e6e00, 
        0xbcbcbc00, 0x8e8e8e00, 0x29292900, 0xf5f5f500, 0xf9f9f900, 0xb6b6b600, 
        0x2f2f2f00, 0xfdfdfd00, 0xb4b4b400, 0x59595900, 0x78787800, 0x98989800, 
        0x06060600, 0x6a6a6a00, 0xe7e7e700, 0x46464600, 0x71717100, 0xbababa00, 
        0xd4d4d400, 0x25252500, 0xababab00, 0x42424200, 0x88888800, 0xa2a2a200, 
        0x8d8d8d00, 0xfafafa00, 0x72727200, 0x07070700, 0xb9b9b900, 0x55555500, 
        0xf8f8f800, 0xeeeeee00, 0xacacac00, 0x0a0a0a00, 0x36363600, 0x49494900, 
        0x2a2a2a00, 0x68686800, 0x3c3c3c00, 0x38383800, 0xf1f1f100, 0xa4a4a400, 
        0x40404000, 0x28282800, 0xd3d3d300, 0x7b7b7b00, 0xbbbbbb00, 0xc9c9c900, 
        0x43434300, 0xc1c1c100, 0x15151500, 0xe3e3e300, 0xadadad00, 0xf4f4f400, 
        0x77777700, 0xc7c7c700, 0x80808000, 0x9e9e9e00
};

private int SBOX4_4404[] = 
{
        0x70700070, 0x2c2c002c, 0xb3b300b3, 0xc0c000c0, 0xe4e400e4, 0x57570057, 
        0xeaea00ea, 0xaeae00ae, 0x23230023, 0x6b6b006b, 0x45450045, 0xa5a500a5, 
        0xeded00ed, 0x4f4f004f, 0x1d1d001d, 0x92920092, 0x86860086, 0xafaf00af, 
        0x7c7c007c, 0x1f1f001f, 0x3e3e003e, 0xdcdc00dc, 0x5e5e005e, 0x0b0b000b, 
        0xa6a600a6, 0x39390039, 0xd5d500d5, 0x5d5d005d, 0xd9d900d9, 0x5a5a005a, 
        0x51510051, 0x6c6c006c, 0x8b8b008b, 0x9a9a009a, 0xfbfb00fb, 0xb0b000b0, 
        0x74740074, 0x2b2b002b, 0xf0f000f0, 0x84840084, 0xdfdf00df, 0xcbcb00cb, 
        0x34340034, 0x76760076, 0x6d6d006d, 0xa9a900a9, 0xd1d100d1, 0x04040004, 
        0x14140014, 0x3a3a003a, 0xdede00de, 0x11110011, 0x32320032, 0x9c9c009c, 
        0x53530053, 0xf2f200f2, 0xfefe00fe, 0xcfcf00cf, 0xc3c300c3, 0x7a7a007a, 
        0x24240024, 0xe8e800e8, 0x60600060, 0x69690069, 0xaaaa00aa, 0xa0a000a0, 
        0xa1a100a1, 0x62620062, 0x54540054, 0x1e1e001e, 0xe0e000e0, 0x64640064, 
        0x10100010, 0x00000000, 0xa3a300a3, 0x75750075, 0x8a8a008a, 0xe6e600e6, 
        0x09090009, 0xdddd00dd, 0x87870087, 0x83830083, 0xcdcd00cd, 0x90900090, 
        0x73730073, 0xf6f600f6, 0x9d9d009d, 0xbfbf00bf, 0x52520052, 0xd8d800d8, 
        0xc8c800c8, 0xc6c600c6, 0x81810081, 0x6f6f006f, 0x13130013, 0x63630063, 
        0xe9e900e9, 0xa7a700a7, 0x9f9f009f, 0xbcbc00bc, 0x29290029, 0xf9f900f9, 
        0x2f2f002f, 0xb4b400b4, 0x78780078, 0x06060006, 0xe7e700e7, 0x71710071, 
        0xd4d400d4, 0xabab00ab, 0x88880088, 0x8d8d008d, 0x72720072, 0xb9b900b9, 
        0xf8f800f8, 0xacac00ac, 0x36360036, 0x2a2a002a, 0x3c3c003c, 0xf1f100f1, 
        0x40400040, 0xd3d300d3, 0xbbbb00bb, 0x43430043, 0x15150015, 0xadad00ad, 
        0x77770077, 0x80800080, 0x82820082, 0xecec00ec, 0x27270027, 0xe5e500e5, 
        0x85850085, 0x35350035, 0x0c0c000c, 0x41410041, 0xefef00ef, 0x93930093, 
        0x19190019, 0x21210021, 0x0e0e000e, 0x4e4e004e, 0x65650065, 0xbdbd00bd, 
        0xb8b800b8, 0x8f8f008f, 0xebeb00eb, 0xcece00ce, 0x30300030, 0x5f5f005f, 
        0xc5c500c5, 0x1a1a001a, 0xe1e100e1, 0xcaca00ca, 0x47470047, 0x3d3d003d, 
        0x01010001, 0xd6d600d6, 0x56560056, 0x4d4d004d, 0x0d0d000d, 0x66660066, 
        0xcccc00cc, 0x2d2d002d, 0x12120012, 0x20200020, 0xb1b100b1, 0x99990099, 
        0x4c4c004c, 0xc2c200c2, 0x7e7e007e, 0x05050005, 0xb7b700b7, 0x31310031, 
        0x17170017, 0xd7d700d7, 0x58580058, 0x61610061, 0x1b1b001b, 0x1c1c001c, 
        0x0f0f000f, 0x16160016, 0x18180018, 0x22220022, 0x44440044, 0xb2b200b2, 
        0xb5b500b5, 0x91910091, 0x08080008, 0xa8a800a8, 0xfcfc00fc, 0x50500050, 
        0xd0d000d0, 0x7d7d007d, 0x89890089, 0x97970097, 0x5b5b005b, 0x95950095, 
        0xffff00ff, 0xd2d200d2, 0xc4c400c4, 0x48480048, 0xf7f700f7, 0xdbdb00db, 
        0x03030003, 0xdada00da, 0x3f3f003f, 0x94940094, 0x5c5c005c, 0x02020002, 
        0x4a4a004a, 0x33330033, 0x67670067, 0xf3f300f3, 0x7f7f007f, 0xe2e200e2, 
        0x9b9b009b, 0x26260026, 0x37370037, 0x3b3b003b, 0x96960096, 0x4b4b004b, 
        0xbebe00be, 0x2e2e002e, 0x79790079, 0x8c8c008c, 0x6e6e006e, 0x8e8e008e, 
        0xf5f500f5, 0xb6b600b6, 0xfdfd00fd, 0x59590059, 0x98980098, 0x6a6a006a, 
        0x46460046, 0xbaba00ba, 0x25250025, 0x42420042, 0xa2a200a2, 0xfafa00fa, 
        0x07070007, 0x55550055, 0xeeee00ee, 0x0a0a000a, 0x49490049, 0x68680068, 
        0x38380038, 0xa4a400a4, 0x28280028, 0x7b7b007b, 0xc9c900c9, 0xc1c100c1, 
        0xe3e300e3, 0xf4f400f4, 0xc7c700c7, 0x9e9e009e
};

private final int SBOX2_0222[] = 
{
        0x00e0e0e0, 0x00050505, 0x00585858, 0x00d9d9d9, 0x00676767, 0x004e4e4e, 
        0x00818181, 0x00cbcbcb, 0x00c9c9c9, 0x000b0b0b, 0x00aeaeae, 0x006a6a6a, 
        0x00d5d5d5, 0x00181818, 0x005d5d5d, 0x00828282, 0x00464646, 0x00dfdfdf, 
        0x00d6d6d6, 0x00272727, 0x008a8a8a, 0x00323232, 0x004b4b4b, 0x00424242, 
        0x00dbdbdb, 0x001c1c1c, 0x009e9e9e, 0x009c9c9c, 0x003a3a3a, 0x00cacaca, 
        0x00252525, 0x007b7b7b, 0x000d0d0d, 0x00717171, 0x005f5f5f, 0x001f1f1f, 
        0x00f8f8f8, 0x00d7d7d7, 0x003e3e3e, 0x009d9d9d, 0x007c7c7c, 0x00606060, 
        0x00b9b9b9, 0x00bebebe, 0x00bcbcbc, 0x008b8b8b, 0x00161616, 0x00343434, 
        0x004d4d4d, 0x00c3c3c3, 0x00727272, 0x00959595, 0x00ababab, 0x008e8e8e, 
        0x00bababa, 0x007a7a7a, 0x00b3b3b3, 0x00020202, 0x00b4b4b4, 0x00adadad, 
        0x00a2a2a2, 0x00acacac, 0x00d8d8d8, 0x009a9a9a, 0x00171717, 0x001a1a1a, 
        0x00353535, 0x00cccccc, 0x00f7f7f7, 0x00999999, 0x00616161, 0x005a5a5a, 
        0x00e8e8e8, 0x00242424, 0x00565656, 0x00404040, 0x00e1e1e1, 0x00636363, 
        0x00090909, 0x00333333, 0x00bfbfbf, 0x00989898, 0x00979797, 0x00858585, 
        0x00686868, 0x00fcfcfc, 0x00ececec, 0x000a0a0a, 0x00dadada, 0x006f6f6f, 
        0x00535353, 0x00626262, 0x00a3a3a3, 0x002e2e2e, 0x00080808, 0x00afafaf, 
        0x00282828, 0x00b0b0b0, 0x00747474, 0x00c2c2c2, 0x00bdbdbd, 0x00363636, 
        0x00222222, 0x00383838, 0x00646464, 0x001e1e1e, 0x00393939, 0x002c2c2c, 
        0x00a6a6a6, 0x00303030, 0x00e5e5e5, 0x00444444, 0x00fdfdfd, 0x00888888, 
        0x009f9f9f, 0x00656565, 0x00878787, 0x006b6b6b, 0x00f4f4f4, 0x00232323, 
        0x00484848, 0x00101010, 0x00d1d1d1, 0x00515151, 0x00c0c0c0, 0x00f9f9f9, 
        0x00d2d2d2, 0x00a0a0a0, 0x00555555, 0x00a1a1a1, 0x00414141, 0x00fafafa, 
        0x00434343, 0x00131313, 0x00c4c4c4, 0x002f2f2f, 0x00a8a8a8, 0x00b6b6b6, 
        0x003c3c3c, 0x002b2b2b, 0x00c1c1c1, 0x00ffffff, 0x00c8c8c8, 0x00a5a5a5, 
        0x00202020, 0x00898989, 0x00000000, 0x00909090, 0x00474747, 0x00efefef, 
        0x00eaeaea, 0x00b7b7b7, 0x00151515, 0x00060606, 0x00cdcdcd, 0x00b5b5b5, 
        0x00121212, 0x007e7e7e, 0x00bbbbbb, 0x00292929, 0x000f0f0f, 0x00b8b8b8, 
        0x00070707, 0x00040404, 0x009b9b9b, 0x00949494, 0x00212121, 0x00666666, 
        0x00e6e6e6, 0x00cecece, 0x00ededed, 0x00e7e7e7, 0x003b3b3b, 0x00fefefe, 
        0x007f7f7f, 0x00c5c5c5, 0x00a4a4a4, 0x00373737, 0x00b1b1b1, 0x004c4c4c, 
        0x00919191, 0x006e6e6e, 0x008d8d8d, 0x00767676, 0x00030303, 0x002d2d2d, 
        0x00dedede, 0x00969696, 0x00262626, 0x007d7d7d, 0x00c6c6c6, 0x005c5c5c, 
        0x00d3d3d3, 0x00f2f2f2, 0x004f4f4f, 0x00191919, 0x003f3f3f, 0x00dcdcdc, 
        0x00797979, 0x001d1d1d, 0x00525252, 0x00ebebeb, 0x00f3f3f3, 0x006d6d6d, 
        0x005e5e5e, 0x00fbfbfb, 0x00696969, 0x00b2b2b2, 0x00f0f0f0, 0x00313131, 
        0x000c0c0c, 0x00d4d4d4, 0x00cfcfcf, 0x008c8c8c, 0x00e2e2e2, 0x00757575, 
        0x00a9a9a9, 0x004a4a4a, 0x00575757, 0x00848484, 0x00111111, 0x00454545, 
        0x001b1b1b, 0x00f5f5f5, 0x00e4e4e4, 0x000e0e0e, 0x00737373, 0x00aaaaaa, 
        0x00f1f1f1, 0x00dddddd, 0x00595959, 0x00141414, 0x006c6c6c, 0x00929292, 
        0x00545454, 0x00d0d0d0, 0x00787878, 0x00707070, 0x00e3e3e3, 0x00494949, 
        0x00808080, 0x00505050, 0x00a7a7a7, 0x00f6f6f6, 0x00777777, 0x00939393, 
        0x00868686, 0x00838383, 0x002a2a2a, 0x00c7c7c7, 0x005b5b5b, 0x00e9e9e9, 
        0x00eeeeee, 0x008f8f8f, 0x00010101, 0x003d3d3d
};

private final int SBOX3_3033[] = 
{
        0x38003838, 0x41004141, 0x16001616, 0x76007676, 0xd900d9d9, 0x93009393, 
        0x60006060, 0xf200f2f2, 0x72007272, 0xc200c2c2, 0xab00abab, 0x9a009a9a, 
        0x75007575, 0x06000606, 0x57005757, 0xa000a0a0, 0x91009191, 0xf700f7f7, 
        0xb500b5b5, 0xc900c9c9, 0xa200a2a2, 0x8c008c8c, 0xd200d2d2, 0x90009090, 
        0xf600f6f6, 0x07000707, 0xa700a7a7, 0x27002727, 0x8e008e8e, 0xb200b2b2, 
        0x49004949, 0xde00dede, 0x43004343, 0x5c005c5c, 0xd700d7d7, 0xc700c7c7, 
        0x3e003e3e, 0xf500f5f5, 0x8f008f8f, 0x67006767, 0x1f001f1f, 0x18001818, 
        0x6e006e6e, 0xaf00afaf, 0x2f002f2f, 0xe200e2e2, 0x85008585, 0x0d000d0d, 
        0x53005353, 0xf000f0f0, 0x9c009c9c, 0x65006565, 0xea00eaea, 0xa300a3a3, 
        0xae00aeae, 0x9e009e9e, 0xec00ecec, 0x80008080, 0x2d002d2d, 0x6b006b6b, 
        0xa800a8a8, 0x2b002b2b, 0x36003636, 0xa600a6a6, 0xc500c5c5, 0x86008686, 
        0x4d004d4d, 0x33003333, 0xfd00fdfd, 0x66006666, 0x58005858, 0x96009696, 
        0x3a003a3a, 0x09000909, 0x95009595, 0x10001010, 0x78007878, 0xd800d8d8, 
        0x42004242, 0xcc00cccc, 0xef00efef, 0x26002626, 0xe500e5e5, 0x61006161, 
        0x1a001a1a, 0x3f003f3f, 0x3b003b3b, 0x82008282, 0xb600b6b6, 0xdb00dbdb, 
        0xd400d4d4, 0x98009898, 0xe800e8e8, 0x8b008b8b, 0x02000202, 0xeb00ebeb, 
        0x0a000a0a, 0x2c002c2c, 0x1d001d1d, 0xb000b0b0, 0x6f006f6f, 0x8d008d8d, 
        0x88008888, 0x0e000e0e, 0x19001919, 0x87008787, 0x4e004e4e, 0x0b000b0b, 
        0xa900a9a9, 0x0c000c0c, 0x79007979, 0x11001111, 0x7f007f7f, 0x22002222, 
        0xe700e7e7, 0x59005959, 0xe100e1e1, 0xda00dada, 0x3d003d3d, 0xc800c8c8, 
        0x12001212, 0x04000404, 0x74007474, 0x54005454, 0x30003030, 0x7e007e7e, 
        0xb400b4b4, 0x28002828, 0x55005555, 0x68006868, 0x50005050, 0xbe00bebe, 
        0xd000d0d0, 0xc400c4c4, 0x31003131, 0xcb00cbcb, 0x2a002a2a, 0xad00adad, 
        0x0f000f0f, 0xca00caca, 0x70007070, 0xff00ffff, 0x32003232, 0x69006969, 
        0x08000808, 0x62006262, 0x00000000, 0x24002424, 0xd100d1d1, 0xfb00fbfb, 
        0xba00baba, 0xed00eded, 0x45004545, 0x81008181, 0x73007373, 0x6d006d6d, 
        0x84008484, 0x9f009f9f, 0xee00eeee, 0x4a004a4a, 0xc300c3c3, 0x2e002e2e, 
        0xc100c1c1, 0x01000101, 0xe600e6e6, 0x25002525, 0x48004848, 0x99009999, 
        0xb900b9b9, 0xb300b3b3, 0x7b007b7b, 0xf900f9f9, 0xce00cece, 0xbf00bfbf, 
        0xdf00dfdf, 0x71007171, 0x29002929, 0xcd00cdcd, 0x6c006c6c, 0x13001313, 
        0x64006464, 0x9b009b9b, 0x63006363, 0x9d009d9d, 0xc000c0c0, 0x4b004b4b, 
        0xb700b7b7, 0xa500a5a5, 0x89008989, 0x5f005f5f, 0xb100b1b1, 0x17001717, 
        0xf400f4f4, 0xbc00bcbc, 0xd300d3d3, 0x46004646, 0xcf00cfcf, 0x37003737, 
        0x5e005e5e, 0x47004747, 0x94009494, 0xfa00fafa, 0xfc00fcfc, 0x5b005b5b, 
        0x97009797, 0xfe00fefe, 0x5a005a5a, 0xac00acac, 0x3c003c3c, 0x4c004c4c, 
        0x03000303, 0x35003535, 0xf300f3f3, 0x23002323, 0xb800b8b8, 0x5d005d5d, 
        0x6a006a6a, 0x92009292, 0xd500d5d5, 0x21002121, 0x44004444, 0x51005151, 
        0xc600c6c6, 0x7d007d7d, 0x39003939, 0x83008383, 0xdc00dcdc, 0xaa00aaaa, 
        0x7c007c7c, 0x77007777, 0x56005656, 0x05000505, 0x1b001b1b, 0xa400a4a4, 
        0x15001515, 0x34003434, 0x1e001e1e, 0x1c001c1c, 0xf800f8f8, 0x52005252, 
        0x20002020, 0x14001414, 0xe900e9e9, 0xbd00bdbd, 0xdd00dddd, 0xe400e4e4, 
        0xa100a1a1, 0xe000e0e0, 0x8a008a8a, 0xf100f1f1, 0xd600d6d6, 0x7a007a7a, 
        0xbb00bbbb, 0xe300e3e3, 0x40004040, 0x4f004f4f
};



private int ct0,ct1,ct2,ct3;
private int pt0,pt1,pt2,pt3;

private int RightRotate(int x, int s){
     return (((x) >>> (s)) + ((x) << (32 - s)));
 };

private long LeftRotate(int x, int s){
    return ((x) << (s)) + ((x) >>> (32 - s)) ;
 };



private void XorBlock(int[] x , int x_ ,int[] y, int y_, int[] z, int z_){
    z[0 + z_] = x[0 + x_] ^ y[0 + y_];
    z[1 + z_] = x[1 + x_] ^ y[1 + y_];
    z[2 + z_] = x[2 + x_] ^ y[2 + y_];
    z[3 + z_] = x[3 + x_] ^ y[3 + y_];
};


private static void RotBlock
(
    int x[], int x_, 
    int n, 
    int y[], int y_
)
{
    int r = (n & 31);    Must not be 0 */
    int idx = (n >>> 5);
    int idx1 = (idx + 1) & 3;
    int idx2 = (idx1 + 1) & 3;

    y[0 + y_] = (x[idx + x_] << r) | (x[idx1 + x_] >>> (32 - r));
    y[1 + y_] = (x[idx1 + x_] << r) | (x[idx2 + x_] >>> (32 - r));
}





private final int SIGMA1[] = {
    0xa09e667f, 0x3bcc908b,
    0xb67ae858, 0x4caa73b2};
private final int SIGMA2[] = {
    0xc6ef372f, 0xe94f82be,
    0x54ff53a5, 0xf1d36f1c};



private final int SIGMA3[] = {
    0x10e527fa, 0xde682d1d,
    0xb05688c2, 0xb3e6c1fd};


private int KSFT1[] = {
    0, 64, 0, 64, 15, 79, 15, 79, 30, 94, 45, 109, 45, 124, 60, 124, 77, 13,
    94, 30, 94, 30, 111, 47, 111, 47 
};

private int KIDX1[] = {
    0, 0, 8, 8, 0, 0, 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 8, 0, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 0, 0, 8, 8 
};



private int KSFT2[] = {
    0, 64, 0, 64, 15, 79, 15, 79, 30, 94, 30, 94, 45, 109, 45, 109, 60, 124, 
    60, 124, 60, 124, 77, 13, 77, 13, 94, 30, 94, 30, 111, 47, 111, 47 
};



private int KIDX2[] = {
    0, 0, 12, 12, 4, 4, 8, 8, 4, 4, 12, 12, 0, 0, 8, 8, 0, 0, 4, 4, 12, 12, 
    0, 0, 8, 8, 4, 4, 8, 8, 0, 0, 12, 12 
};

private void Camellia_Feistel
(
    int[] x, int x_, 
    int[] k, int k_,
    int key_offset
)
{
    int D, U;
    int s1, s2;

    s1 = x[0 + x_] ^ k[0 + k_];

    U  = SBOX4_4404[s1 & 0x000000FF];
    U ^= SBOX3_3033[(s1 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
    U ^= SBOX2_0222[(s1 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
    U ^= SBOX1_1110[(s1 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];
    s2 = x[1 + x_] ^ k[1 + k_];
    D  = SBOX1_1110[s2 & 0x000000FF];
    D ^= SBOX4_4404[(s2 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
    D ^= SBOX3_3033[(s2 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
    D ^= SBOX2_0222[(s2 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];

    x[2 + x_] ^= D ^ U ;
    x[3 + x_] ^= D ^ U ^ RightRotate(U, 8); 

    s1 = x[2 + x_] ^ k[key_offset + k_];
    U = SBOX4_4404[s1 & 0x000000FF];
    U ^= SBOX3_3033[(s1 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
    U ^= SBOX2_0222[(s1 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
    U ^= SBOX1_1110[(s1 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];
    s2 = x[3 + x_] ^ k[key_offset+1 + k_];
    D = SBOX1_1110[s2 & 0x000000FF];
    D ^= SBOX4_4404[(s2 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
    D ^= SBOX3_3033[(s2 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
    D ^= SBOX2_0222[(s2 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];

    x[0 + x_] ^= D ^ U  ;
    x[1 + x_] ^= D ^ U ^ RightRotate(U, 8) ;

}



private void Camellia_Feistel_Enc
(
    int[] k, int k_
)
{
    int D, U;
    int s1, s2;

    s1 = ct0 ^ k[0 + k_];

    U  = SBOX4_4404[s1 & 0x000000FF];
    U ^= SBOX3_3033[(s1 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
    U ^= SBOX2_0222[(s1 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
    U ^= SBOX1_1110[(s1 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];
    s2 = ct1  ^ k[1 + k_];
    D  = SBOX1_1110[s2 & 0x000000FF];
    D ^= SBOX4_4404[(s2 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
    D ^= SBOX3_3033[(s2 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
    D ^= SBOX2_0222[(s2 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];

    ct2 ^= D ^ U ;
    ct3 ^= D ^ U ^ RightRotate(U, 8); 

    s1 = ct2  ^ k[2 + k_];
    U = SBOX4_4404[s1 & 0x000000FF];
    U ^= SBOX3_3033[(s1 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
    U ^= SBOX2_0222[(s1 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
    U ^= SBOX1_1110[(s1 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];
    s2 = ct3 ^ k[3 + k_];
    D = SBOX1_1110[s2 & 0x000000FF];
    D ^= SBOX4_4404[(s2 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
    D ^= SBOX3_3033[(s2 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
    D ^= SBOX2_0222[(s2 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];

    ct0 ^= D ^ U  ;
    ct1 ^= D ^ U ^ RightRotate(U, 8) ;

}

private void Camellia_Feistel_Dec
(
    int[] k, int k_
)
{
    int D, U;
    int s1, s2;

    s1 = pt0 ^ k[0 + k_];

    U  = SBOX4_4404[s1 & 0x000000FF];
    U ^= SBOX3_3033[(s1 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
    U ^= SBOX2_0222[(s1 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
    U ^= SBOX1_1110[(s1 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];
    s2 = pt1  ^ k[1 + k_];
    D  = SBOX1_1110[s2 & 0x000000FF];
    D ^= SBOX4_4404[(s2 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
    D ^= SBOX3_3033[(s2 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
    D ^= SBOX2_0222[(s2 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];

    pt2 ^= D ^ U ;
    pt3 ^= D ^ U ^ RightRotate(U, 8); 

    s1 = pt2  ^ k[k_ - 2];
    U = SBOX4_4404[s1 & 0x000000FF];
    U ^= SBOX3_3033[(s1 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
    U ^= SBOX2_0222[(s1 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
    U ^= SBOX1_1110[(s1 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];
    s2 = pt3 ^ k[k_ - 1];
    D = SBOX1_1110[s2 & 0x000000FF];
    D ^= SBOX4_4404[(s2 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
    D ^= SBOX3_3033[(s2 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
    D ^= SBOX2_0222[(s2 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];

    pt0 ^= D ^ U  ;
    pt1 ^= D ^ U ^ RightRotate(U, 8) ;

}

public void Camellia_Ekeygen
(
    int[] rawKey, 
    int[] keyTable
)
{
    int t[] = new int[16];
    int  i;

    memcpy(t, 0, rawKey, 0, 4);
     for (i = 4; i < 8; i++) t[i] = 0;


    XorBlock(t, 0, t , 4, t, 8);
    Camellia_Feistel(t, 8, SIGMA1, 0, 2);
    XorBlock(t, 8, t, 0, t, 8);
    Camellia_Feistel(t, 8, SIGMA2, 0, 2);
    memcpy(keyTable, 0, t, 0, 16);
    memcpy(keyTable, 4, t, 8, 8);

        for (i = 4; i < 26; i += 2 ){
            RotBlock(t , KIDX1[i + 0], KSFT1[i + 0], keyTable, i*2);
            RotBlock(t , KIDX1[i + 1], KSFT1[i + 1], keyTable, i*2+2);
        }

}

public  void Camellia_EncryptBlock
( 
    int plaintext[], 
    int keyTable[], 
    int ciphertext[]
)
{
    int j;
    int grandRounds;

    int k = 4; 

    ct0 = keyTable[0] ^ (plaintext[0]);
    ct1 = keyTable[1] ^ (plaintext[1]);
    ct2 = keyTable[2] ^ (plaintext[2]);
    ct3 = keyTable[3] ^ (plaintext[3]);

    for (grandRounds = 0; grandRounds < 3; grandRounds++)
    {System.out.println("gd"+String.valueOf(grandRounds));
            for (j = 0; j < 6; j+=2, k += 4)
                Camellia_Feistel_Enc(keyTable,k);

        if (grandRounds < 2)
        {
            ct1 ^= LeftRotate(ct0 & keyTable[k + 0], 1);
            ct0 ^= ct1 | keyTable[k + 1];
            ct2 ^= ct3 | keyTable[k + 3];
            ct3 ^= LeftRotate(ct2 & keyTable[k + 2], 1);
            k += 4;
        }
    }

    ciphertext[0] = keyTable[k + 0] ^ (ct2);
    ciphertext[1] = keyTable[k + 1] ^ (ct3);
    ciphertext[2] = keyTable[k + 2] ^ (ct0);
    ciphertext[3] = keyTable[k + 3] ^ (ct1);

}

public void Camellia_DecryptBlock 
( 
    int ciphertext[], 
    int keyTable[], 
    int plaintext[] 
)
{
    int grandRounds;
    int j;
    int k; 

    k = 48;
    System.out.println("gd");
    pt0 = keyTable[k + 0] ^ (ciphertext[0]);
    pt1 = keyTable[k + 1] ^ (ciphertext[1]);
    pt2 = keyTable[k + 2] ^ (ciphertext[2]);
    pt3 = keyTable[k + 3] ^ (ciphertext[3]);

    k -= 2;

    for (grandRounds = 0; grandRounds < 3; grandRounds++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j+=2, k -= 4)
            Camellia_Feistel_Dec(keyTable,k);

        if (grandRounds < 2)
        {
            pt1 ^= LeftRotate(pt0 & keyTable[k + 0], 1);
            pt0 ^= pt1 | keyTable[k + 1];
            pt2 ^= pt3 | keyTable[k - 1];
            pt3 ^= LeftRotate(pt2 & keyTable[k - 2], 1);
            k -= 4;
        }
    }

    k -= 2;

    plaintext[0] = keyTable[k + 0] ^ (pt2);
    plaintext[1] = keyTable[k + 1] ^ (pt3);
    plaintext[2] = keyTable[k + 2] ^ (pt0);
    plaintext[3] = keyTable[k + 3] ^ (pt1);

}

private static final void memcpy(int[] dst , int dst_ ,int[] src, int src_ ,int leng)
{
    for(int i=0; i < leng ;i++){
            dst[i + dst_]=src[i + src_];
    }
}
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a={0,2};
     int[] b={0,3};
     int[]c={0,4};
     Newclass n=new Newclass();

      n.Camellia_EncryptBlock(a, b, c); 
    }
};
```

Comment: This is a great way to learn some debugging. Read the stacktrace, look up the line where the error appeared, set a break point there in your IDE and let it run again (with debugging) to see which values all the variables have.

Comment: from https://info.isl.ntt.co.jp/crypt/eng/camellia/source_past.html, with name : Crypto engine for Camellia (Java, BSD License)
 camellia-java-BSD-1.0.1.tar.gz (Version 1.0, 8 KB)
MD5:e899bfc9e986cf30460c1420f73df607 @Artjom B.
SHA1:8c950fe2e3be337b7686bdf2238b6584898ff334

Comment: try this https://info.isl.ntt.co.jp/crypt/eng/camellia/dl/camellia-java-BSD-1.0.1.tar.gz, i download v 1.0.1 different version different code :D @ArtjomB.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Method `Camellia_EncryptBlock` definition. which have three `int` Array as parameter `(plaintext , keyTable , cipherText)`.

Problem with this code.

```
public  void Camellia_EncryptBlock(int plaintext[], int keyTable[], int ciphertext[] )

ct0 = keyTable[0] ^ (plaintext[0]);
ct1 = keyTable[1] ^ (plaintext[1]);
//these two line create Exception 
ct2 = keyTable[2] ^ (plaintext[2]); //try to access beyond the array Index.
ct3 = keyTable[3] ^ (plaintext[3]); // plaintext[2] and [3] is OutOfIndex.
```

Declaration nd definition is fine. Now Here you are calling this method in `main` .

```
int[] a={0,2}; //array of Size 2. So Index will be 0 and 1
 int[] b={0,3};  //array of Size 2. So Index will be 0 and 1
 int[]c={0,4};  //array of Size 2. So Index will be 0 and 1
 Newclass n=new Newclass();

  n.Camellia_EncryptBlock(a, b, c); // a, b and c are int array of size 2.
```

And your are trying to access index `3` and `4` here. which raise `ArrayOutofBoundException`

```
    ct2 = keyTable[2] ^ (plaintext[2]); //try to access beyond the array Index.
    ct3 = keyTable[3] ^ (plaintext[3]); // plaintext[2] and [3] is OutOfIndex.
```

Hope you got your mistake

Answer (score 0):

As the variable name says, `keyTable` is not the key, but the result of a key schedule that is necessary for Camellia. The key schedule can be seen in [section 3.4 of the specification](https://info.isl.ntt.co.jp/crypt/eng/camellia/dl/01espec.pdf#8).

That's what `Camellia_Ekeygen` is for:

```
int[] key = {0, 1, 2, 3}; // 128 bit key example
int[] keyTable = new int[52];
n.Camellia_Ekeygen(key, keyTable);

int[] plaintext = {4, 5, 6, 7}; // 128 bit plaintext block example
int[] ciphertext = new int[4];
n.Camellia_EncryptBlock(plaintext, keyTable, ciphertext);
```

Camellia supports key sizes of 128, 192 and 256 bit. The given `Camellia_Ekeygen` method only supports 128 bit keys. The newest version (currently 1.2.0) provides proper encryption for all valid key sizes.

Comment: i try your code but eror in this code    y[0 + y_] = (x[idx + x_] << r) | (x[idx1 + x_] >>> (32 - r)); , eror is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16
 at javaapplication1.Newclass.RotBlock(Newclass.java:275)
 at javaapplication1.Newclass.Camellia_Ekeygen(Newclass.java:469)
 at javaapplication1.Newclass.main(Newclass.java:570), but when i write int[] keyTable = new int[32]; eror in line 276,  you know about camellia @Artjom B.

Comment: Yes, the keytable should be larger than I anticipated.

Comment: but when i write int[] keyTable = new int[32]; eror in line 276, you know about camellia @Artjom B

Comment: I've used 54 as the size. I haven't run your code. I've just provided an answer by reading your code.

Comment: I fixed the size again: 52 ints is enough and I've fixed the other compile error. See my updated code and it [works on ideone](http://ideone.com/8p6lMO).

Answer (score -1):

when i write 64 key tabele this code i get result, so this is chiper text with camelia wit input int[] plaintext = new int[]{4, 5, 6, 7,4}; and key int[] key = {0, 1, 2, 3};
int[] keyTable = new int[54]; ???

```
333198842
-716115841
-415093582
1481898330
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      Newclass n=new Newclass();
  int[] key = {0, 1, 2, 3};
int[] keyTable = new int[64];
n.Camellia_Ekeygen(key, keyTable);

int[] plaintext = new int[]{4, 5, 6, 7,4};
int[] ciphertext = new int[4];
n.Camellia_EncryptBlock(plaintext, keyTable, ciphertext); 
 }

public  void Camellia_EncryptBlock
( 
    int plaintext[], 
    int keyTable[], 
    int ciphertext[]
)
{
    int j;
    int grandRounds;

    int k = 4; 

    ct0 = keyTable[0] ^ (plaintext[0]);
    ct1 = keyTable[1] ^ (plaintext[1]);
    ct2 = keyTable[2] ^ (plaintext[2]);
    ct3 = keyTable[3] ^ (plaintext[3]);

    for (grandRounds = 0; grandRounds < 3; grandRounds++)
    {
            for (j = 0; j < 6; j+=2, k += 4)
                Camellia_Feistel_Enc(keyTable,k);

        if (grandRounds < 2)
        {
            ct1 ^= LeftRotate(ct0 & keyTable[k + 0], 1);
            ct0 ^= ct1 | keyTable[k + 1];
            ct2 ^= ct3 | keyTable[k + 3];
            ct3 ^= LeftRotate(ct2 & keyTable[k + 2], 1);
            k += 4;
        }
    }

    ciphertext[0] = keyTable[k + 0] ^ (ct2);
    ciphertext[1] = keyTable[k + 1] ^ (ct3);
    ciphertext[2] = keyTable[k + 2] ^ (ct0);
    ciphertext[3] = keyTable[k + 3] ^ (ct1);
   System.out.println(String.valueOf(ciphertext[0]));
     System.out.println(String.valueOf(ciphertext[1]));
       System.out.println(String.valueOf(ciphertext[2]));
         System.out.println(String.valueOf(ciphertext[3]));
}
```

Comment: oh sorry sir, i'm new in this forum thankz about your  attention heheheh, so how about my code, is that rigth about result chiper text camellia?? @ArtjomB.

Comment: This is basically the same as my answer now, but uses a larger than necessary keyTable. You may delete it.